# upload photo to facebook via graph api (URL)

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have made photos website with wordpress and for 4 years i used facebook graph api to upload photos to facebook from my website, it takes url of image and upload it via url, now since facebook has changed graph api to 2.10 my app does not work anymore, i was using 2.3 , and i am not a developer , all i have done was from google search, now i dont know how to make it work again, check my website here 
http://www.punjabidharti.com/pd/english-fonts/
now when i click on upload to fb buttonit show page isnt woking..

This Is My Index File

```
try {
    $access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
    $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
  . "url=" . urlencode($_POST["source"])
  . "&message=" . urlencode($_POST['message'])
  . "&method=POST"
  . "&access_token=" .$access_token;
    $response=file_get_contents($graph_url);
    $json=json_decode($response);
  }
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log('Could not post image to Facebook.');
  }
}
```

Base_facebook.php

```
public function getType() {
    if (isset($this->result['error'])) {
        $error = $this->result['error'];
        if (is_string($error)) {
            // OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 style
            return $error;
        } else if (is_array($error)) {
            // OAuth 2.0 Draft 00 style
            if (isset($error['type'])) {
                return $error['type'];
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using these files 
https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src

If you need another file please tell me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the changelog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Most likely there is an exception occurring that is not of type FacebookApiException, so it does not get caught by your catch block, and therefor the script as a whole ends with a fatal error. Change that part to `catch ($e) { var_dump($e); }` and see what you get.

Comment: Parse error when i try your method